# Will this if statment cause bad things to happen?

Tags: c#, if-statement, operator-precedence

```
int expenseCode;
if (int.TryParse(sourceRecord.ExpenseCode, out expenseCode) && _ExpenseCodeLookup.ContainsKey(expenseCode))
{
     destRow.PROFIT_CENTER_NAME = _ExpenseCodeLookup[expenseCode];
}
else
     destRow.PROFIT_CENTER_NAME = "Unknown";
```

The thing I am conerned about is will the first expression  always be run (setting `expenseCode` in the process) before the second operation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's fine. `&&` is short-circuiting in C#, and the `out` parameter will definitely have been assigned the appropriate value by `TryParse` before `ContainsKey` is called.

On the other hand, you could use the same trick again to fetch the value:

```
string profitCenter;
int expenseCode;
if (int.TryParse(sourceRecord.ExpenseCode, out expenseCode) && 
    _ExpenseCodeLookup.TryGetValue(expenseCode, out profitCenter))
{
    destRow.PROFIT_CENTER_NAME = profitCenter;
}
else
{
    destRow.PROFIT_CENTER_NAME = "Unknown";
}
```

This way you're only doing the lookup of the expense code once.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the TryGetValue!

Answer (score 6):

No, it won't cause bad things to happen!

The `&&` operator guarantees not to evaluate the right operand if the left operand evaluates to false. This is called short-circuiting.

Similarly, `||` operator will not evaluate the right operand if the left operand evaluates to true.

The non-short-circuiting versions of these operators for boolean values are `&` and `|`. They will evaluate both operands regardless of the value of the left hand side.

Answer (score 3):

The statement is fine, `&&` will short circuit, which means the right hand side is contingent upon the left. So if `TryParse` returns true, then `expenseCode` will be populated with a valid integer, and then the right function will execute.